# Keep lxml from creating self-closing tags

Tags: python, lxml

I have a (old) tool which does not understand self-closing tags like `<STATUS/>`. So, we need to serialize our XML files with opened/closed tags like this: `<STATUS></STATUS>`.

Currently I have:

```
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> para = """<ERROR>The status is <STATUS></STATUS>.</ERROR>"""
>>> tree = etree.XML(para)
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<ERROR>The status is <STATUS/>.</ERROR>'
```

How can I serialize with opened/closed tags?

```
<ERROR>The status is <STATUS></STATUS>.</ERROR>
```

**Solution**

Given by [wildwilhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1062499/wildwilhelm), [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41890892/1513933):

```
>>> from lxml import etree

>>> para = """<ERROR>The status is <STATUS></STATUS>.</ERROR>"""
>>> tree = etree.XML(para)
>>> for status_elem in tree.xpath("//STATUS[string() = '']"):
...     status_elem.text = ""
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<ERROR>The status is <STATUS></STATUS>.</ERROR>'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems like the `<STATUS>` tag gets assigned a `text` attribute of `None`:

```
>>> tree[0]
<Element STATUS at 0x11708d4d0>
>>> tree[0].text
>>> tree[0].text is None
True
```

If you set the `text` attribute of the `<STATUS>` tag to an empty string, you should get what you're looking for:

```
>>> tree[0].text = ''
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
'<ERROR>The status is <STATUS></STATUS>.</ERROR>'
```

With this is mind, you can probably walk a DOM tree and fix up `text` attributes before writing out your XML.  Something like this:

```
# prevent creation of self-closing tags
for node in tree.iter():
    if node.text is None:
        node.text = ''
```

Comment: Is there an easy solution to put the closing tag with the same indentation as the opening tag on the line below ?

Answer (score 8):

If you tostring lxml dom is `HTML`, you can use

```
etree.tostring(html_dom, method='html')
```

to prevent self-closing tag like `<a />`