# Append XML tag and attributes that has open and close tag Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to build the xml below. I want to be able to append more `<mcastChannel attrs></mcastChannel>` tags to this xml. I am instead getting .

I did read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52717176/force-elementtree-to-use-closing-tag) to a similar question but I could not append this to the XML_STR_Config.

XML trying to build:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ewe mask="0x80" hw_type="100" br="SC" release="5.3.0-10">
  <probe>
    <core>
      <setup>
        <mcastnames>
          <mclist xmlChildren="list">
            <mcastChannel attrs></mcastChannel>
            <mcastChannel attrs></mcastChannel>
          </mclist>
        </mcastnames>
      </setup>
    </core>
  </probe>
</ewe>
```

My Current Code:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element
CHANNEL_DATA = [['nameTest', '225.0.0.1']]
APPEND_CONFIG = ('mcastChannel name="{}" tuningId="{}" addr="{}"')
xml_root = ElementTree.ElementTree(
ElementTree.fromstring(XML_STR_CONFIG))
multicast_xml_child = xml_root.getroot()[0][0][0][0][0]

for tuning_id, data in enumerate(CHANNEL_DATA):
  multicast_xml_child.append(Element(APPEND_CONFIG.format(data[0], tuning_id, data[1])))
  xml_root.write(output_file, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method='xml')
```

Result:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ewe br="SC" hw_type="100" mask="0x80" release="5.4.0-10">
  <probe>
    <core>
      <setup>
        <mcastnames>
          <mclist xmlChildren="list">
          <mcastChannel name="test" tuningId="0" addr=""/>
          <mcastChannel name="test" tuningId="1" addr="225.1.0.0"/>
        </mcastnames>
      </setup>
    </core>
  </probe>
</ewe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set an 'empty' text for the element:

```
root = etree.Element('root')
root.text = ''
print (etree.tostring(root))
```

returns:

```
<root></root>
```

Comment: I had to add root.tail = '\n' to separate each append but the root.text = '  ' did provide the open and close tag. Thanks!

Comment: Weirdly neither works for me.

Comment: Found a solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61627743/1548275