# Modify only text and keep everything others exactly the same using lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

When I use write() method to change text values in a XML file, I noticed that the header was auto-corrected & reformatted, and tags with empty text were self-closed which was not what I want.

QUESTION:

How to affect texts ONLY and keep everything others STRICTLY unchanged when trying to modify the XML file using the module lxml(or possibly other modules)?

For example, the original file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SAMPLE_CUST [
  <!ELEMENT SAMPLE_CUST (DATA_RECORD*)>
  <!ELEMENT DATA_RECORD (DV_ID?,CUSTOMERID?,CUSTNAME?,FIRSTNAME?,LASTNNAME?,C_TYPE?,DOB?,EMAIL?,ADDRESS?,CCARD?,ORGNAME?)+>
  <!ELEMENT DV_ID (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT CUSTOMERID (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT CUSTNAME (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT FIRSTNAME (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT LASTNNAME (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT C_TYPE (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT DOB (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT EMAIL (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ADDRESS (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT CCARD (#PCDATA)>
  <!ELEMENT ORGNAME (#PCDATA)>
]>
<SAMPLE_CUST>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DV_ID>6,297,411,002</DV_ID>
    <CUSTOMERID>6,297,411,002</CUSTOMERID>
    <CUSTNAME>GUILLE CW &amp; CF</CUSTNAME>
    <FIRSTNAME></FIRSTNAME>
    <LASTNNAME></LASTNNAME>
    <C_TYPE>O</C_TYPE>
    <DOB>1954-04-15 00:00:00</DOB>
    <EMAIL>isotopian@att.net</EMAIL>
    <ADDRESS>54 MAXWELL DRIVE</ADDRESS>
    <CCARD>3.48796E+14</CCARD>
    <ORGNAME>SILVER CHEF LIMITED</ORGNAME>
  </DATA_RECORD>
</SAMPLE_CUST>
```

However, after changing, I got:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ASCII'?>
<!DOCTYPE SAMPLE_CUST [
<!ELEMENT SAMPLE_CUST (DATA_RECORD)*>
<!ELEMENT DATA_RECORD (DV_ID? , CUSTOMERID? , CUSTNAME? , FIRSTNAME? , LASTNNAME? , C_TYPE? , DOB? , EMAIL? , ADDRESS? , CCARD? , ORGNAME?)+>
<!ELEMENT DV_ID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CUSTOMERID (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CUSTNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT FIRSTNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT LASTNNAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT C_TYPE (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT DOB (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT EMAIL (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ADDRESS (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT CCARD (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ORGNAME (#PCDATA)>
]>
<SAMPLE_CUST>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <DV_ID>6,297,411,002</DV_ID>
    <CUSTOMERID>6,297,411,002</CUSTOMERID>
    <CUSTNAME>GUILLE CW &amp; CF</CUSTNAME>
    <FIRSTNAME/>
    <LASTNNAME/>
    <C_TYPE>O</C_TYPE>
    <DOB>1954-04-15 00:00:00</DOB>
    <EMAIL>isotopian@att.net</EMAIL>
    <ADDRESS>54 MAXWELL DRIVE</ADDRESS>
    <CCARD>3.48796E+14</CCARD>
    <ORGNAME>KIN MINING NL</ORGNAME>
  </DATA_RECORD>
</SAMPLE_CUST>
```

Notice:

1. Double quotes were changed to single quotes, e.g.xml version="1.0" to xml version='1.0'
2. Encoding was automatically added after write()
3. Sub-elements in element DATA_RECORD were automatically separated by white spaces
4. Empty tags like FIRSTNAME and LASTNNAME were automatically self-closed

Comment: None of the listed changes (except maybe encoding) materially differ from original XML. All compliant DOM libraries should parse both equivalently outside of text change for `<ORGNAME>` node.

Comment: @Parfait The point is, I have some special requirements to have to keep the consistency as much as possible to the original file even though they are equivalent, are there any ways to change text only without touching any other parts?

Comment: Regarding self-closed empty elements, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/41890415/407651

Comment: ElementTree (but not lxml) has a `short_empty_elements` option for controlling serialization of empty elements. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write